# Support of a global section being a closed set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In Vakil's "the rising sea" book, it reads, and I quote:

"Suppose $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf (or indeed separated presheaf) of abelian groups on $X$, and $s$ is a global section of $\mathscr F$. Then let the support of $s$, denoted $Supp(s)$, be the points $p$ of $X$ where $s$ has a nonzero germ:
$Supp(s)$ := {$p \in X : s_p \neq 0$ in $\mathscr F_p$}.

...Show that Supp(s) is a closed subset of $X$."

I just figure out a proof of this proposition without using the identity axiom... So does it require that $\mathscr F$ must be a sheaf (or indeed separated presheaf)?

Here is my proof:

Suppose $p \in X-Supp(s)$, then $[(s,X)] = 0$ in $\mathscr F_p$.([] marks the representative of the equivalence class), it implies that $\exists U$ such that $p \in U$ and $s \mid U$ is the $0$ element in $\mathscr  F(U)$.

Now it suffices to prove that for any $p1 \in U$, we have $p1 \in X-Supp(s)$, that is, $[(s,X)] = 0$ in $\mathscr F_{p1}$.(Then $X-Supp(s)$ would be an open set of $X$.)

For any $[(t,V)] \in \mathscr F_{p1}$(which means $p1 \in V,t \in \mathscr  F(V)$), $p1 \in U, V$, so $p1 \in U \cap V$. We know that $s \mid U$ is the $0$ element in $\mathscr  F(U)$, so $s \mid U \cap V$ is the $0$ element in $\mathscr  F(U \cap V)$ since a group homomorphism maps $0$ element to $0$ element.

$[(s,X)] + [(t,V)]=[(s \mid U,U)] + [(t,V)] = [(s \mid U \cap V,U \cap V)] + [(t \mid U \cap V,U \cap V)] = [(0,U \cap V)] + [(t \mid U \cap V,U \cap V)] =  [(t \mid U \cap V,U \cap V)] = [(t,V)]$

End of proof.

I do not use the identity axiom in my proof! What is going wrong in the proof?

Comment: FYI, this is the [second time](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4657423/revisions) you've typo'd "The Rising Sea" as "The Raising Sea".

Comment: oh, I correct it now. Thanks.